# How to check false-equal object efficiently in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering does there exist an efficient way for us to check false-equal object or primitive in javascript.

For example, assume there is an array with length 1. It could be `[undefined]`, `[<1 empty item>]`, `[[]]`, `[null]`, `[NaN]`, `[new Set()]` and so on. How could we check the element quickly?

I thought of the above problem because I was writing codes for an algorithm question, there was a case that I needed to use a `for` loop

```
for (var x of a) { x.......}
```

The structure of the given `a` was kind of complicated, I once used `x === undefined || x.length === 0` to ensure x is not false-qual, but it seems to be inapplicable for the case that `x` is `null` or `x` is an empty `new Map()`. By compared, in other languages such as python, we only need to write `if not x: ...` to remove the false-equal element.

Comment: _“By compared, in other languages such as python, we only need to write `if not x`”_ — so why not just `!(x && x.length)`?

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm, it seems like you're right. thx :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use `arr.toString()` first, all of your provided falsy arrays will be convert to an empty string: `''`, except `[new Set()]`

```js
[new Set()].toString()
"[object Set]"
```

so if you get a truly string, you can detect the first element of your array then, such as `(new Set()).size`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Truthiness in JavaScript 
list of falsy values in javascript [falsy values][1]  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

in your case it is if(x){.....}